# MongoDB golang driver CreateCollection doesn't create a collection

Tags: database, mongodb, go, mongo-go-driver

Whenever I try the simple method Createcollection like this:
`client.Database("TestCluster").CreateCollection(context.TODO(), "users", options.CreateCollection().SetMaxDocuments(100000))`

And I access mongoDB Atlas (free tier) seems like it doesn't have any collection created.
My assumption is that I cannot create a collection unless I put some data in it.
(I cannot create an empty collection).

Can somebody shine me some light? Thanks :)

Docs:
https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#CreateCollectionOptions.SetMaxDocuments
https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Database.CreateCollection

Comment: **Never** omit errors in Go. The returned error says: `(InvalidOptions) the 'capped' field needs to be true when either the 'size' or 'max' fields are present`

Answer (score 0):

Dumb me...!
Whenever `SetMaxDocuments()` is called you also need to set `SetCapped(true)`
So yes, it's possible to have an empty collection :)